# Issue using CMake : gtk module

Tags: gtk, cmake, compilation

I'm attempting to compile zzogl using CMake and I keep running into issues.  My first issue stated that I needed pkgconfig, so I installed that, for which I also had to install MacPorts.  Then it said I needed gtk+-2.0 module, so I got that too.  After that took forever to install, I still get this error:

```
checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
package 'gtk+-2.0' not found
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-2.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/Applications/CMake 2.8-2.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
CMakeLists.txt:106 (pkg_check_modules)


CMake Error at cmake/funcs.cmake:32 (message):
gtk not found, aborting...
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/funcs.cmake:23 (reportFound)
CMakeLists.txt:107 (checkFor)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm not really familiar with what I am doin, and it is completely possible I am doing it all wrong.  Anyone have any incite into my problem?  I am using a mac with snow leopard btw.

Answer (score 3):

Did you install gtk with a command similar to `sudo port install gtk2`? If yes, then normally gtk should be found by cmake. You can test if gtk is correctly found by pkg-config manually like this:

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0
```

which should print something like

```
-pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12
```

but with different paths, the above is on a Linux system.

If indeed the pkg-config call succeeds, something is wrong with your CMake config. You might then try to install the MacPorts version of cmake like this: `sudo port install cmake` and use this one.

Comment: Thanks for the response but after running pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 I got   basically what you had but replace -I/usr/lib/gtk       with:  -I/opt/local/include/gtk-2.0   etc.   I then tried installing cmake again with the command line, then tried compiling again.  I ended up with the same error as my previous try, verbatim.

Comment: Did you start CMake from the same terminal in which pkg-config worked? Then I'm really out of ideas...

Comment: Originally I was running a Cmake application with a gui.  However this time around I ran it in command line using:  cmake zzogl.  I assume that was correct?

Comment: Yes. With cmake you normally work out of source. That means you go to the source directory, e.g. ~/src/zzogl. Then you say mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..

Comment: Ya I'm really not sure what the problem is, Cmake just doesn't seem to be able to locate gtk, I suppose maybe I installed gtk improperly, or perhaps the wrong gtk module?  Oh well, thanks for trying.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. pkg-config finds everything just fine, but I get the following cmake error:

-- Some or all of the gtk libraries were not found.  (missing:  GTK2_GLIBCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR GTK2_GDKCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR)

Comment: Reinstalling `cmake` and `gtk2` worked for me. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I had a look into the `FindGTK2.cmake` module and I think I see the problem: It doesn't use `pkg-config`, but does its own way of finding headers and libraries. The `_GTK2_FIND_INCLUDE_DIR` function doesn't have `/opt/local/include/` in its list of directories, which is where MacPorts is probably going to install the headers. Similarly, `_GTK2_FIND_LIBRARY` doesn't list `/opt/local/lib`.

This is a [known bug](http://www.vtk.org/Bug/view.php?id=10688), which was apparently fixed in [CMake 2.8.3-rc1](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/59). I have my doubts, though, because they didn't update the library path. We'll see.

I looked at the documentation for [`find_path`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3afind_path) and [`find_library`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3afind_library). It appears that the user can give hints about the search path by specifying `-D` options to `cmake`. Try something like:

```
cmake ../zzogl -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
```

Comment: Great! The -DCMAKE_*_PATH didn't work for me, but the patch at the given link did.  I just copied the FindGTK2.cmake into a CMakeModules directory in my source dir, made the changes from the patch, and added set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules/") to my main CMakeLists.txt.